# Regex look-behinds in textcomplete.js

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have `textcomplete.js` plugin, that search all content after `@....`, with this regex:

```
/\B@([\-+\w]*)$/
```

I return text in span like this:

```
<span contenteditable="false" class="highlight">@example</span>&nbsp;
```

And in my text in web page I see it like this:

```
@example |
```

> ( | -> place of my cursor )

If go back with cursor like this:

```
@example|
```

textcomplete fires and show me drop down, but i don't need it, so i try to find way, to change my regex, so that it doesn't find @text when it starts with

```
<span>@text
```

I try this, in regex online, it works:

```
/\B^(?!\>)@([\-+\w]*)$/
```

But in my project doesn't work.
I tried [something like this](https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete/issues/139), but this is a bit too hard for me

Can anyone help me?

EDITED:
In few words
I want to find regex expression , that finds this:

```
@exampletext
```

But don't find this:

```
<span>@exampletext
```

When cursor is behind last character of the word

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Comment: "This is a bit too hard for me" is not a problem statement. Include what the unexpected outcome or exception is, and state the problem clearly.

Comment: Problem is that i want to disable textcomplete on those '@texts', wich starts with <span>, because when i write '@example', then i need textcomplete dropdown, but when i have getted that word, and replaced it in my text with '<span>@example', then i dont need to show dropdown, when cursor is at the end of this word

Comment: Try this `^(?:(?!<span>).)*@`

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
(^(?!@).).+
```

Example and explanation: http://regex101.com/r/jL2fH0/2

What it does here is checks to make sure the string doesn't begin with an @ before matching the rest. Note that in this example I've added the gmi flags - you may not want to use these given your requirements, they're just in there to demonstrate the regex working.

Note too that we have to do this workaround since JavaScript doesn't support negative lookbehinds.

Comment: But i need it to begin with @, i need to check if it begin with span or not. In regex i need just those @example , where they won't start with <span>

Comment: Really not sure what you're asking, your question (and this comment) aren't very clear. I've given you a good starting point though, so hopefully you can utilize that and create a working expression.

Comment: In some words - i have text. When i write @, i want my textcomplete dropdown. I get it with my regex. But after i choose word from dropdown, and insert it in my text, i don't want to see dropdown, when i place my cursor at end of that word. But it happens, because of regex. And only difference, between dynamic '@word', and already inserted '@word', is that inserted word has <span> in front of it

Comment: Can't you do something really basic then like `<span>@`? Matches <span>@ and doesn't match anything else.